# Extjs4.1 -- How to create a subclass for render / send a parameter?

Tags: extjs4, subclass

I have a checkitem menu and I want to add icons to each menu item, so I inserted each icon after the menu item is rendered.

peace of my code:

```
{   xtype: 'menucheckitem',
     text: 'First Arrow'
     listeners: {
           render: {
                 fn: me.onMenucheckitemRender,
                 scope: me
                        }
                     }
}



onMenucheckitemRender: function (abstractcomponent, options)
{
Ext.DomHelper.insertAfter(abstractcomponent.getEl().down(".x-menu-item-icon"), {
    tag: 'img', 
    src: "icons/arrow1.png"
});
}
```

This works just fine, but since I will need it many times with different icons, I would like to know how to create a subclass so I can reuse this functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [`Ext.define`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-define) method and the [`extend`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-extend) property.

```
Ext.define('SomeNamespace.menu.menucheckitemWithIcon', {
  extand: 'Ext.menu.CheckItem',
  alias: 'widget.menucheckitemWithIcon',

  .
  .
  . 

});
```

Comment: How would I change icon url each time?